# Ranks in 2 races

Tags: logical-deduction

8 competitors (A-H) participated in 2 races. The first was the practice race, and the second being the final one. No 2 people got the same rank.

A and B improved their ranks in the final race by 5 spaces each. C did worse than G in the final race. G became worse by 5 spaces in the final race. C did better than E and F in the practice race. D came first in the practice race, but became 4th in the final race. E and F swapped ranks in the final race.

How did the winner of the final race fare in the practice one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The winner of the final race was

> H, who placed 3rd or 4th in the practice race.

Explanation:

You have 8 possible places in each race. We know that D was 1st in the practice, 4th in the final, so we can fill him in.

```
   P  F
1  D
2
3
4     D
5
6
7
8
```

Next we know G got worse by 5 spaces, which means he was either 1,2, or 3 in the practice race and 6,7, or 8 in the final race. However, D was 1 in practice, and C was worse than G in the final, so G must have gotten 2 and 7 in the respective races.

```
   P  F
1  D
2  G
3
4     D
5
6
7     G
8     C
```

E and F switched spots in the final race, so they can't be in spots 4,7, or 8 in the practice race. C did better than E and F in the practice race, so they must be in slots 5 and 6 in both races (doesn't matter which order).

```
   P  F
1  D
2  G
3  
4     D
5  E  F
6  F  E
7     G
8     C
```

A and B moved up five spaces in the final race, so they must be in slots 7 and 8 in the practice race and 2 and 3 in the final race (doesn't matter which order).

```
   P  F
1  D
2  G  A
3     B
4     D
5  E  F
6  F  E
7  A  G
8  B  C
```

That leaves H in the remaining places: 3rd or 4th in the practice race, 1st in the final race.

Comment: Why can't H be 3rd and C be 4th in the practice race?

Comment: Well, you even got the explanation before I did! :-) Question though: how do you know C came 3rd and not 4th in the practice race?

Comment: That was an error on my part, for some reason I was filling C, E and F into spots 3, 5, and 6 in the third step, but of course C could be in 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

In the practice race:

- **D came first** (given)
- G came second or third, since he has room to become worse by 5 spaces; also C did worse than G in the final race, so **G came second**
- A and B were both in the last three, since they had room to improve by 5 spaces
- C came third or fourth, since E, F, A, B must all be worse than C

In the final race:

- **D came fourth** (given)
- A and B were both in the top three, since they improved by 5 spaces
- **G came seventh**, since he became worse by 5 spaces
- **C came eighth**, since she did worse than G
- one of H, E, F was in the top three and the other two were fifth and sixth

Since **E and F** swapped places, the only possibility is now that they were **fifth and sixth** in both races. That means **A and B** were **seventh and eighth** in the practice race and therefore **second and third** in the final race. So:

> H won the final race, and came third or fourth in the practice race.